# Laravel 5.2 Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am familiar with how to use Eloquent relationships but I am struggling to get my head around this particular scenario.

I have `users` and `addresses` tables.

A user can have many addresses, but users can also share an address. So I need to create a `user_addresses` table.

The `user_addresses` table looks like this...

*id*, *user_id*, *address_id*

How do I set up my relationships so I can retrieve all the addresses for a particular user, so I could do something like `$user_addresses = $user->addresses()`

Comment: Are you adding more complexity than needed? What is the problem with each user having its own set of addresses, even if those addresses happen to contain the same information?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins a situation could be a default address, on a update check if its the default address and create a new addres if he had the default one.

Comment: So, you're not familiar enough :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship which uses belongToMany:

in your User model

```
public function addresses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Address', 'user_addresses');
}
```

You can call $user->addresses to acces the values, you do not need to put them in a variable if you pass the user to your view, you can just call $user->addresses.

If you rename your table to 'address_user' you can use:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Address');
```

The name of the table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names.

Comment: Unfortunattely your first answer won't work if he doesn't have column in pivot table called `addresses_id`

Comment: @FilipKoblański nope you can use address_id because the name of the model is used + _id.

Comment: True you got that right :) my mistake, sorry... +1 for you

Comment: @FilipKoblański no problem i was just curious if i missed something.